# Outputting a 1/4 inch TRS male plug from a PCB

Tags: pcb-design, trs

I am designing a small PCB that I need to plug into a 1/4" TRS receptacle. The overall setup can either be something like a small dongle (i.e. attaching a male TRS directly to the PCB somehow,) or I can use an approximately 1-2 foot long cable. I don’t want a cable much longer than that because the low-power electronics on my PCB will need to drive it.

My main challenge is finding a TRS cable where the termination on the end that I would connect to my PCB is something convenient. I have seen 1/4" male TRS to mini USB male. That's a possibility, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant or more standard approach.

The signal is just a digital HI/LOW, so no analog to worry about.

Comment: Why not make your own cable - you can solder wires to a 1/4 inch TRS plug.  I would expect a TRS-to-USB cable to have some electronics in it (audio interface or ??) - it doesn't make sense to connect a TRS plug directly to USB.

Comment: Are you using just the tip of the TRS or both tip and ring? I take it you don't have enough room to just put a TRS jack on your PCB and use a TRS-TRS cable?

Comment: @td127 I'm using only the tip for the signal (ring and sleeve are both ground). A friend of mine just mentioned the same solution of putting a TRS jack on the PCB, since if the cable fails, it can easily be replaced. I think that's what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get a plug (without cable) and wire it up to whatever connector you want for your PCB, or just directly solder wires to the PCB if you don't need the plug to be detachable. Distributors like [Mouser](https://www.mouser.de/Connectors/Audio-Video-Connectors/Phone-Connectors/_/N-778cv?P=1yzvc3fZ1z0yxti) have lots of options (click for relevant results).